# Next Prev entries with low alphabet

Tags: low-alphabet

Anyone know if it's possible to have prev/next entry linking on a single entry page using Low Alphabet (with params for ignoring 'the', etc.) - couldn't see anything on this in the docs

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, prev/next entries is currently not available in Low Alphabet.

Comment: ok - good to know!